# Implementing environment based configuration

Tags: java, spring

I am in the process of developing a spring web application. The application uses the Stripe API to handle payment processing. Simply put, I wanted to get opinions on which of these 2 approaches to configuring Stripe. Depending on whether the application is 'live' or in 'production', you use different public and private keys as part of the Stripe configuration. I am considering these 2 approaches. Would using a profile be overkill?

Using Spring Profiles:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("live")
public class StripeConfigLive{

    @Bean
    public MyStripeOperationsHandler getStripeOpsHandler() {
       return new MyStripeOperationsHandler(livePrivKey, livePubKey);
    }

}



@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class StripeConfigDev{

    @Bean
    public MyStripeOperationsHandler getStripeOpsHandler() {
       return new MyStripeOperationsHandler(devPrivKey, devPubKey);
    }

}

@Controller
public class MyController {

   @Autowired
   private MyStripeOperationsHandler stripeOperationsHandler;

   //use the handler to respond to requests

}
```

Or, simply specifying the run mode as a context param in web.xml:

```
    public class MyController implements ServletContextAware {

        private MyStripeOperationsHandler stripeOperationsHandler;

        private ServletContext servletContext;

         @PostConstruct
         public void init() {
            RunMode runMode = RunMode.valueOf(servletContext.getInitParameter("runMode"));

            switch (runMode) {
            //init the MyStripeOperationsHandler 
            }

         }

         @Override
         public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
            this.servletContext = servletContext;
         }

     //use the handler to respond to requests

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use 'Spring Profile'. Because if tomorrow you want to enhance the functionality like using different 'dataSources' for different environment you can use same technique(spring profiling) to achieve multiple purposes.